# Laravel (API): I need to insert the post with Multiple Blog categories by using API Request (React)

Tags: api, database-design, laravel-5.6

I am trying to create a functionality for blog post which suppose to add by using front application which is built on react and my api which is built on Laravel (5.6),

I have tried couple of things, but unfortunately I am unable to figure out how can I attach multiple blog categories with single post

**BlogPostAPIController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $BlogPosts = new BlogPosts;
    $BlogPosts->tutor_id = $request->user()->tutor->id;
    $BlogPosts->title = $request->title;
    $BlogPosts->BlogCategories = $request->BlogCategories; /* Unknown column*/
    $BlogPosts->slug = str_slug($request->title);
    $BlogPosts->short_description = $request->short_description;
    $BlogPosts->post_content = json_encode($request->post_content);
    $BlogPosts->featured_image = $request->featured_image;
    $BlogPosts->status = $request->status;

    $BlogPosts->BlogCategories()->attach($request->blog_categories_id);
    $BlogPosts->save();

    return $BlogPosts::create($request->all());
}
```

**BlogPostsModel.php**

```
class BlogPosts extends Model{
public $table = 'blog_posts';

const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public $fillable = [
    'tutor_id',
    'title',
    'slug',
    'short_description',
    'post_content',
    'featured_image',
    'status'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
    'tutor_id' => 'integer',
    'title' => 'string',
    'slug' => 'string',
    'short_description' => 'string',
    'post_content' => 'string',
    'featured_image' => 'string',
    'status' => 'string'
];

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $rules = [

];

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 **/
public function tutor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Tutor::class);
}

public function BlogCategories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(BlogCategories::class);
}

// Category.php
public function BlogPosts(){
    return $this->hasMany(BlogPosts::class);
}
```

}

**BlogCategoryBlogPost.php**

```
Schema::create('blog_categories_blog_posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('blog_categories_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('blog_posts_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('blog_categories_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('blog_posts_id')->references('id')->on('blog_posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

**API Response**

[Please find the screenshot for API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILJTg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should save model before set relations, otherwise model doesn't have primary key (id) to set relations.
2. Better to use sync with belongsToMany relations (conveniently to update).
3. You should return saved model, now you create duplicate and return it.
4. Category belongsToMany Posts, and Post belongsToMany Categories.

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $BlogPosts = new BlogPosts;
    $BlogPosts->tutor_id = $request->user()->tutor->id;
    $BlogPosts->title = $request->title;
    $BlogPosts->slug = str_slug($request->title);
    $BlogPosts->short_description = $request->short_description;
    $BlogPosts->post_content = json_encode($request->post_content);
    $BlogPosts->featured_image = $request->featured_image;
    $BlogPosts->status = $request->status;

    $BlogPosts->save();

    $BlogPosts->BlogCategories()->sync($request->blog_categories_id);

    return $BlogPosts;
}
```

BlogPosts model:

```
public function BlogCategories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(BlogCategories::class, 'blog_categories_blog_posts');
}
```

BlogCategories model:

```
public function BlogPosts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(BlogPosts::class, 'blog_categories_blog_posts');
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Works perfect, Thanks a lot

Comment: Just one mistake I noticed in your code
**Before**
$BlogPosts->tutor_id = user()->tutor->id;

**after**

$BlogPosts->tutor_id = $request->user()->tutor->id;